# How to read the contents of a variable with Netldap

Tags: perl, ldap, netldap

I'm writing a script that receives as a parameter the name of a user and performs a search in LDAP but I can't find a way to use a Perl variable in the LDAP search filter.

The code used is this one :

```
package cnmodule;

sub function1 {

  use strict;
  use Net::LDAP;

  my ($local) = @_;
  my $valueA;

  my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new('ad.network',version => 3) 
    or die "Can t connect to LDAP ($@)";

  $valueA = $ldap->bind ("cn=usercheck,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=network", password => 'password'); 
  $valueA->code && die $valueA->error;

  $valueA= $ldap->search(
    base => 'dc=domain,dc=network',
    scope => 'sub',
    filter => '(sn=$local)', 
  );

  $ldap->unbind();

  $valueA->code && die $valueA->error;
  foreach my $entry ($valueA->all_entries) {
    my $valueB = $entry->get_value('CN'); 
  }
  return $valueB;
}

$variableA='test';
$variableB=function1($variableA);
print $variableB;
1;
```

The variable "$local" contains the name I need to do the search and is used in the ldap filter, but with this script LDAP doesn't receive the content of this variable and therefore doesn't return anything.

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Comment: I've fixed the indentation of your code. You're very welcome, but please consider doing it yourself next time. Careful indentation is a very useful tool for helping people understand your code. And if you're asking a large number of strangers to read and understand your code then it's only polite to make that as easy as possible for them.

Comment: Note that `use` statements are usually put at the top of the file - certainly outside of any subroutines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$valueA= $ldap->search(
  base => 'dc=domain,dc=network',
  scope => 'sub',
  filter => '(sn=$local)', 
);
```

Or, more specifically, here:

```
  filter => '(sn=$local)',
```

Perl (like many programming languages) doesn't expand variables in a single-quoted string. So you're sending the literal string `(sn=$local)`. The fix is simple - change to using a double-quoted string.

```
  filter => "(sn=$local)",
```